# Button Onclick not working with public functions - UNITY3D C#

Tags: c#, android, button, unity-game-engine

I'm making an Android game, I assigned `public onClick` functions to three buttons on the canvas and they're not working on my Android Phone or by clicking them on my computer. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

And here is my code for the ball, as you can see I'm trying to make the ball move forward with the `ForwardSLASHleft` function, backwards with the `BackwardsSlashRight` function, and start with the `StartButton` function. But none of them are working.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class ballScript : MonoBehaviour {
    Rigidbody rb;
    public float thrust;
    public Button left;
    public Button right;
    public Button startB;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        gameObject.SetActive(false);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);

    }

    public void StartButton()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        left.enabled = true;
        right.enabled = true;
        startB.enabled = false;

    }

    public void forwardSLASHleft()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.right * -1 * thrust);
    }

    public void backwardsSLASHright()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.right * 1 * thrust);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Drag your script to your Buttons Onclick component and select your function

**Also make sure that you have EventSystem GameObject**